# Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address. Code -32602

Tags: web3js

Here is the transaction I am trying to send using `web3.eth.sendTransaction`:

```
{
   data: "0x11a861a700...."
   from: "0x8ccb1711ea5562596f146608fdcf27ccf0d5429c"
   gas: "0x6b540"
   gasPrice: "0xaf16b1bb3"
   nonce: "0x0"
   to: "0x7113dd99c79aff93d54cfa4b2885576535a132de"
   value: "0x38d7ea4c68000"
}
```

It keeps getting back with the following message:

**MetaMask - RPC Error: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address.**

Is there some kind of other form this TX should be fed to web3?

edit. This transaction was generated by https://1inch.exchange/#/api using the following GET request:

```
https://api.1inch.exchange/v1.1/swap?fromTokenSymbol=ETH&toTokenSymbol=BAT&amount=2000000000000000&fromAddress=0x8ccb1711ea5562596f146608fdcf27ccf0d5ZYZc&slippage=1&disableEstimate=true
```

edit. XYZ addresses are just placeholders.

Comment: Well, neither `0x8ccb1711ea5562596f146608fdcf27ccf0d54XYZ` nor `0x7113dd99c79aff93d54cfa4b2885576535a13XYZ` is a valid Ethereum address, so what exactly are you expecting???

Comment: @goodvibration I am simply concealing my addresses.

Comment: Why? It's not a private key that needs to be concealed!

Comment: anything else to add?

Comment: Try to encapsulate each one of them with `Web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(...)`.

Comment: BTW, there is no `toAddress` value in your GET request.

Comment: I too am facing the same issue. I have two buttons on the page both pointing to different wallet addresses; First Button: <button class="sendEthButton btn-donation" id="charity-button">Send to charity wallet</button>
<script>
const sendEthButton = document.querySelector('#charity-button'); let accounts = []; //Sending donation to charity wallet
sendEthButton.addEventListener('click', () => { ethereum .request({ method: 'eth_sendTransaction', params: [ { from: accounts[0], to:'0x900CEB06*****************e5AD841F2a50673', value: '0x38d7ea4c68000', gasPrice: '', gas: '', }, ], }) .then((txHash) =

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, and it was not about specifying a wrong address in terms of format (incorrect hexadecimal structure), but putting one of the addresses in the wrong place within the parameters of the transaction. In my case:

```
    const txParams = {
        from: fromAccount,  // The error was here!
        to: toAccount,
        data: encodedData,
        value: 0,
        chainId: chainId,
    };
```

When calling the function from a contract, I incorrectly put the contract address in the **'from'** instead of putting the caller address.

Therefore, I assume this issue should be normally addressed by reviewing that  **'from'** and **'to'** addresses are correctly set.

Comment: Hi can you please have a look at my question. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120470/remix-invalid-parameters-must-provide-an-ethereum-address

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue as well when I forgot to provide the transaction parameters in an array.

Bad:

```js
ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_sendTransaction', params: txParams })
```

> MetaMask - RPC Error: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address.

Good:

```js
ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_sendTransaction', params: [txParams] })
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and in my case, the wallet was not connected to the web site. A simple click on "connect" in Metamask did the job. Kind of a misleading error message in this scenario.

Comment: Hi can you please have a look at my question. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120470/remix-invalid-parameters-must-provide-an-ethereum-address

Comment: I was connected, but my metamask was not on my connected wallet. By only changing the wallet it worked