# Remix: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address

Tags: remix, rinkeby

I have a contract ready for deployment on REMIX and also have 3 Rinkeby Metamask accounts. Only 1 of these accounts is able to deploy the contract for some reason. When i try the other 2 accounts i keep getting

`creation of TestContract errored: Invalid parameters: must provide an Ethereum address.`

I have deployed the exact same contract before and it was working fine.

Why am i getting this error & why is only one of the accounts able to deploy?

Comment: Can you please provide more info like the addresses on Rinkeby and/or a screenshot of the screen when trying to deploy.

Comment: Have you connected the 2nd and 3rd account to remix? If you haven't metamask won't allow remix to interact with them.

Comment: @Ismael yes they are connected. The only way it works is if i change the environment from injected web3 to anything else then back to injected web3, which is a pain.

Comment: It looks like a remix bug. You should report to their github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and was able to fix it by disconnecting the Remix account and then reconnecting it.